# Safari can't open web link sent from windows PC.

Tags: windows, macos, share, smb

I want to share web link \172.16.100.78\AboutViewController.m.html (located in my windows pc, shared by SMB) to my MAC peer, but can't open it by Safari. Any format error? How to correct?

Seems always work well between two windows PC.

Thank you.

Comment: Macs don't recognise *windows* network paths of the form `\\server\path` directly.

Comment: Then how to share a html file to MAC?